# How can I export the link dataframe from a network graph in igraph?

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I have a randomly generated graph like the following:

```
 g <- erdos.renyi.game(30, 151 , type = "gnm" , directed = F , loops = F)%>%
 set_vertex_attr("a", value = 0)
```

Is there a way that I can retrieve a link dataframe that looks like this:

```
id   id2
 1     2
 1     3
 2     4
 3     5
 4     5
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "link dataframe"? What output do you want exactly?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. You should ask questions defining your inputs and outputs very clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I edited the question to depict a general format of the output I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for seems to be what igraph calls the "edge list". You can get that with

```
as_edgelist(g)
```

or if you want to include vertex attributes,

```
as_long_data_frame(g)
```